# Make legend wrap in 2 lines with ellipsis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a packed bubble highcharts: https://jsfiddle.net/3yc24qxn/

Code:

```
I'm tyring to figure out the color change.
```

Comment: Given how separate the concerns of these questions are I'd probably prefer them being separate. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `labelFormatter` function and add `<br>` tag to the returned string.

   ```
   legend: {
     labelFormatter: function() {
       return 'text <br> text'
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use color axis with disabled `showInLegend` option.

   ```
   colorAxis: {
     showInLegend: false
   }
   ```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3xozk08q/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/color-axis

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter

Comment: hmmm, I tried adding both these properties: https://jsfiddle.net/409xf3d1/ But I dont see it working.

Comment: Hi @Ant's, You need to also add the coloraxis module: `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/coloraxis.js"></script>`. As to the question about a legend, do you mean the created custom label, not the default legend?

Comment: Yes, the custom label one, not the default one.

Comment: Setting `ellipsis` for text in two lines is tricky. You need to enable `useHTML` for the created labels and manually set styles, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1nycgdot/ Useful thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909489/text-overflow-ellipsis-on-two-lines