# How to use text-overflow:ellipsis for 3 line truncate?

Tags: css

How can I use ellipsis in CSS to truncate after 3 lines of text, rather than 1?

I have this so far, but it only works for text on a single line. I want the text to wrap twice (for a quote).

```
.truncate {
    width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [With CSS, use "..." for overflowed block of multi-lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cannot be done in all css3 browsers yet, only webkit.

```
.line-clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

I use [clamp.js](https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js) if I really need to truncate

Comment: Actually it's now supported on all major browsers - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/