# Why webkit line clamping does not work in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I use this webkit line clamp, it works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. The following is the code:

```
{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4; /* number of lines to show */
  line-height: X; /* fallback */
  max-height: X * 4; /* fallback */
}
```

How should I make it work on Firefox as well?

Comment: Because Firefox doesn't use WebKit...?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. I just wanted another way to implement the same function. Got it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Important Update:

As of **Firefox version 68** [Firefox supports `-webkit-line-clamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/68#CSS)!!

**Demo snippet** ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=line-clamp))

```css
p {
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3; /* number of lines to show */
}
```

```html
<p>When the CSS -webkit-line-clamp property is applied to a block of text (e.g., a paragraph), the text is limited to the specified number of lines (1 or more), and an ellipsis character (…) is added to the end of the last visible line. - see <a href="https://webplatform.news/issues/2019-05-17">webplatform.news</a>
```

Although Firefox uses the [Gecko rendering Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29) which uses the `-moz-` vendor prefix, since version 49, [Firefox decided to add support for several `-webkit-` prefixes](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/09/firefox-49-fixes-sites-designed-with-webkit-in-mind-and-more/) and WebKit-specific interfaces

**Note:** [CSS Overflow Module Level 3 Editor's draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3) includes an official property [line-clamp](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#line-clamp) - which will likely replace the proprietary`-webkit-line-clamp` property.

### Original Answer

You can't. `-webkit-line-clamp` is for browsers that use webkit. Firefox runs on [gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29) and uses the vendor prefix: `-moz-`

If you're interested - you could take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458345/703717): a [line-clamp with fade-out fallback fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/DpQ7e/30/) which adds a fade-out effect workaround (instead of ellipsis) for non-webkit browsers.

Comment: It still won't work on Firefox since it doesn't support *-webkit-line-clamp*.

Comment: Not Working on firefox... @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: still not working in firefox, despite their claims that it does now

Comment: @Pixelomo - It won't work on firefox until version 68. Firefox has a pre-release browser called firefox nightly... I tested there and it is currently working

Comment: ah right, well bleeding edge builds dont really count since most users dont use them, any idea when 68 will be released to the main browser?

Comment: Well firefox is currently at version 66, so I'm guessing that version 68 will be released in about a month or two.

Comment: @Pixelomo - Firefox version 68 has been released and I have verified that it supports `-webkit-line-clamp`

Comment: @Danield that's good, wasn't any use back in May when I needed it though

Comment: Also supported by Safari 5+ as claimed here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/

Answer (score 1):

/*----line clamp---*/

```
.line-clamp {
    position: relative;
    height: 2.7em; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.line-clamp:after {
    background: $white;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
    content: '\2026';
    margin-left: -3rem;
    width: 1rem;
}

@supports (-webkit-line-clamp: 2) {
    .line-clamp {
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        / autoprefixer: off /
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical; 
        / autoprefixer: on /
        max-height:3.6em; 
        height: auto;
    }
    .line-clamp:after {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

/*----line clamp end---*/

Answer (score 0):

In firefox, -webkit-line-clamp don't work

Here a javascript code that works fine
http://codepen.io/nilsynils/pen/zKNpkm?editors=1111

```
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(containers, (container) => {  // Loop through each container
    var p = container.querySelector('p');
    var divh = container.clientHeight;
    while (p.offsetHeight > divh) { // Check if the paragraph's height is taller than the container's height. If it is:
        p.textContent = p.textContent.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...'); // add an ellipsis at the last shown space
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just face thisi issue on latest Firefox with TailwindCSS and I fixed it by following code:

```css
[class*="line-clamp-"]:not(.line-clamp-none) * {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
{
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
    display: -webkit-box;    
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    /* number-of lines */    
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical; 
    word-wrap:break-word;    
    line-height:1.2; 
    /* line-height for 1line*/    
    max-height:3.6rem; 
    /* line-height * 3*/
}
```

it works fine with chrome, ff, ie, edge

Comment: [`-webkit-line-clamp` is not supported by Firefox 58-61, IE 11 or Edge 16-17.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp)

Comment: @Gaʀʀʏ Edge supports it with -webkit prefix in Edge 17-18, according to the link

Comment: @Gaʀʀʏ update 2021: `-webkit-line-clamp` is now supported by all major browsers with the `-webkit` prefix.