# Truncating text to specifc number of lines after formatting

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a site which will display some videos from the YouTube API, and **truncates the video description to 170 characters** on the server side. They have to go in a narrow box so whenever it contains URLs or long words which make it wrap a lot, it can sometimes overflow out of the container. Is there a **client side way to truncate the strings** and add an ellipsis on the end (I could use overflow:hidden but I can't use an ellipsis with that. It's my last resort).

Here below is an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image: It should look like this]

Comment: What's your code look like for what you're doing now? Can you provide a jsfiddle so we can see what you're trying to do already?

Comment: See: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines) and [this](http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/)

Comment: @teabos thanks! The stackoverflow you linked with the jquery plugin was just what I was looking for.

Comment: I'd go with Yuriy's suggestion over a jQuery plugin.

Comment: @StormDrive I agree with APAD1, go for a css solution over jQuery if you can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [text-overflow:ellipses;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) but unfortunately this only works with `white-space:nowrap` which is I don't think you need.

What you *can* do is do `overflow:hidden` like you intended and fake ellipses with pseudo-element `:after`.

Imaginge you have you DIV with text:

```
<div id="text">
    (really long text here)
</div>
```

Styled like this:

```
#text {
    background:white; 
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Just add to it

```
#text:after {
    content:'...';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background:inherit
}
```

And bingo: http://jsfiddle.net/tFZEb/3/

Comment: Works fine except that it still adds it even if the string is truncated, but with a small amount of javascript I can fix that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

The only native way to end with ellipsis a multiline text is 
-webkit-box & -webkit-line-clamp wich has very low support.

```
div{
 width:150px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/rmy2Y/

else you need to find some css hacks or js scripts.