# Text-overflow does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I my page i have a panel and a table in the panel, this is my code in [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/nmW3B/)

I have a problem in my code, in `td` of table i have text and i set `text-overflow` for that but it doesn't show correctly. it shows like this :

[image]

But i want text shows like this:

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: why do you use  `white-space: nowrap;`, remove it and look for result

Comment: as FLCL says remove white-space: nowrap; and see the result here http://jsfiddle.net/nmW3B/4/

Comment: Removing `white-space: nowrap;` won't do what OP wants. He does want to wrap it, only after more characters are shown. Because he used the same text twice in his example it's quite confusing. But he wants to cut of the text after the first fringilla.

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis;` does not work on multi-line strings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines

Comment: @FLCL: you right but it doesn't show ... at the end. i want text shows like the second image that i upload.

Comment: @ElhamGdz, hm, I have understand. Try to change `info-table td` css selector to `info-table td p`, and `...` will appear, but the problem may be that as @Prunzhorn said it will not work on multi-line strings

Comment: So we have 5 incorrect answers below:) and look like 1 correct!

Comment: @FLCL: you right i change `info-table td css` selector to `info-table td p` and `...` will appear, but just one line will show, i want show more than one line, it means no way for this?

Comment: @Felix answer is correct for chrome, hope you may find solution for other browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give your paragraph a class for easier to manage:

```
<p class="text">...............</p>
```

Then you can use following css properties to achieve your task:

```
.text {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;    
    -webkit-line-clamp: 6; 
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmW3B/11/)**

Comment: Only answer that understood the OP question so it seems =). Is there a crossbrowser alternative for this?

Comment: @Felix: your answer just correct for chrome, it doesn't work in FireFox, do you have any idea ?

Comment: For firefox, the alternative way is to use a fade out fallback, check this article from `csstricks`: http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nmW3B/7/)**

change your code

**FROM THIS**

```
.info-table td {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: inherit;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

**TO THIS**

```
.info-table td {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**EDITED CODE** [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nmW3B/13/)

```
.info-table td p{
    max-height:260px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: i want text shows like second image that i upload, your code doesn't show ... at the end.

Comment: @ElhamGdz simply remove max-width from <p>

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you, remove the text-overflow and white-space from td.

```
.info-table td {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nmW3B/6/)

Answer (score 0):

> remove the `white-space: nowrap;` property in your css, you will get

Answer (score 0):

Actually overflow works only on single line that's why your all content shrink onto one line.

you may use some jQuery/Javascript library like this http://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/ or try a pure css solution using this tuts
http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

Answer (score -2):

increase the height of div. i think due to less size it showing like this