# Text-overflow is not working

Tags: jquery, css, html, overflow

**Details :**

I have problem in css **text-overflow**.
Actually my div contains large text content but I want it to display only four lines and I want to remove this overlapping content.
How could I achieve this?

*My overlapping content*

[image: overlapping div]

**CSS Code :**

```
.divclass {
    width:90%;
    display: block;
    float: right; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: try to specify height

Comment: providing a jsfiddle link would be a 'plus'

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6222616/703717

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can't use pure css `text-overflow` with multi-line text](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) (sorry)

You'd be best using something like [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".divclass").dotdotdot();
});
```

Comment: ok i will try this but is that possible to achieve this without using jquery?

Comment: The only way would be to limit the height of the div using `max-height:  30px;`

Answer (score 1):

As a curiosity, it can be done with webkit browsers:

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 4;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub string in javascript or try this:

***Sample:***

```
var strings = 'Text contents';
if(strings.length > 10) 
strings = strings.substring(0,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your .divclass a specified height

```
 .divclass { max-height: 150px; }
```

or whatever max-height your four lines require

Comment: @Ahni i agree with you but i have one question . if suppose i increase my font-size again same problem will come right?

Comment: Yes, increasing the font-size will eventually make the text behave the same way it  is behaving now, if it exceeds the height boundries. Better keep a particular font-size for this div.

Answer (score 0):

try this white-space:nowrap;

```
.divclass {
width:90%;
display: block;
float: right; 
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap; 
}
```

Comment: In your code only one line is displaying but i want to display first four lines and at the end of the fourth line '...'

Answer (score -1):

Use this, It's work without jQuery

```
.divclass {
            height:25px;
            overflow:hidden;
            width:50%;
            text-overflow:ellipsis;
            display:block;
            white-space:nowrap;
        }
```