# Limit white-space to two lines of wrapping

Tags: css

I have this review box seen in image below. It is a div. I set the width and height on the box, and I have float element to the right.

Now the text is overflowing the box, I want it to show ellipsis instead of overflowing. I tried `overflow:hidden` on the box and it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Instead of floating the left side element use `display:table` for box and used `table-cell` for inner items. and then for text part use `text-overflow:ellipsis`.

Comment: Thanks for replies everyone. This project of mine went on s two week hold. I'll be getting back to it this week so will research these answers. So @janaspage I'm not sure of answer as I didn't read these replies yet but the answer may be in this topic. If not, if u find out anything plaza do share

Answer (score 3):

you can't use `text-overflow: ellipsis` for multiline text, you can achieve it purely with CSS like shown in this page: [CSS Ellipsis](http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/), though it will be harder to do it than using a jQuery plugin.

the easier way is to use a jQuery plugin, like mentioned by Jim Thomas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines)