# HTML Large text with dotted end

Tags: html, css

I want to display text inside a fixed size div if the size of text is large than more text should be indicated with dots.

example

if number of text can be displayed inside div is 10 then

text "Australia" should be displayed like "Australia"
text "United States Of America" should be displayed like "United Sta..."

Comment: Look here http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis

Comment: [**Text-overflow:ellipsis @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: Google gets a lot more helpful when you know the name of what you're trying to do.. these are called 'ellipsis': http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: [my solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18458345/703717) may also help you as it shows some methods for a multi-line ellipsis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the CSS property you're looking for:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

For example:

```
<div style="width: 5em; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
    United States of America
</div>
```

Will display

> United St...

The text must be in one line (hence the `white-space: nowrap`), and overflow a box where the overflow is hidden (hence the `overflow: hidden`). Fiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2y8hxjd2/).

Comment: Note: `white-space: nowrap;` is also essential here

Comment: This is working only for single line, but according to user it may multiple lines.

Comment: @SameeraThilakasiri That's not specified in the question. Is that why you downvoted me?

Comment: @SameeraThilakasiri There is no point to give a down voting. If OP needs different solution he should be clear while writing question. +1 from me Rooby.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS to the div.

```
 div
    {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    }
```

Hope it help