# How to use text-overflow:ellipsis?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html - http://jsfiddle.net/o8e4n30n/

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <span class="badge">14</span>
        <span class="txt">Cras justo sto odio asdasda sdas dasdasdasda sdadadsadssto odio asdasda sdas dasdasdasda sdadadsadssto odio asdasda sdas dasdasdasda sdadadsadsodio asdasda sdas dasdasdasda sdadadsads</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to use text-overflow ellipsis property so that only a single line is shown with a ... instead of the 3 lines which are shown now

i.e from

> > Cras justo sto odio asdasda sdas dasdasdasda sdadadsadssto odio asdasda sdas dasdasdasda sdadadsadssto odio asdasda sdas dasdasdasda sdadadsadsodio asdasda sdas dasdasdasda sdadadsads

to

> > Cras justo sto odio asdasda sdas dasdasdasda sdadadsadssto odio asdasda sdas dasdasdasd…

Please advice.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25282323/3558960).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8e4n30n/2/) to add the necessary styling:

```
.list-group-item {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The text must be in one line (hence the `white-space: nowrap`), and overflow a box where the overflow is hidden (hence the `overflow: hidden`).

I've applied the styles on the list element because  it's a block level element by default. If you want to apply it on the `span`, you would have to add a `display: block` rule, or add a `display: inline-block` rule with an associated `width`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a specific width and overflow for the element with text-overflow: ellipsis.

What about:

```
.list-group-item {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Follow this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) to learn more.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/toyibakenihi/2) to play around.

Answer (score 0):

USE:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
text-wrap:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
```

Hope it helps