# Break text into three lines with overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

Let's say I have this text:

"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

And I want to display it with specified width and line count(3) like that:

```
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaa...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With CSS, use "..." for overflowed block of multi-lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines)

Comment: I would use js here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html Code:

```
<div class="parent">  
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabdbdbdfbdbdbdfbdbdsb
</div>
```

Css Code:

```
.parent{width:100px;word-break:break-all;}
```

Jsfiddle:-

https://jsfiddle.net/Dhavalr/apzy68vp/1/

Comment: How can I limit this to 3 lines? –

Comment: Then you can use js for restricting some amount of characters and then ellipsis.

There is webkit property to show only 3 lines in chrome

display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;

Comment: Ok. It works fina on chrom. Is there a property for other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
<style>
p.text {
/* your costume with & height*/
    width: 11em;
    max-height: 3.6em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    word-wrap: break-word;

}
</style>
```