# How to use text-overflow:ellipsis in full height of div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show a long text in block of div and want that if a text exceed to div height then need to show a "..." otherwise fill a whole text in to a block.

But problem is that, using CSS `text-overflow:ellipsis` will cut the whole long text into one line text and place these dots where more text can be written into in below space.

```css
.hide-long-text {
  height: 80px;
  width: 110px;
  border: 1px solid #adb8c0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide-long-text">Now a long wooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooooooord</div>
```

here is a fiddler [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rzq05ja4/4/)

Can someone give me a hint how I can use this free space and when text exceed the div height then show "..."

Comment: I want to clarify that the question is about truncating text to always fit the container's height, whatever it might be.

Comment: [CSSWG-Drafts discussion regarding this](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/9368)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please try the code:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    div {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      line-height: 20px;
      word-break: break-all;
      background-color: skyblue;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -moz-box-orient: vertical;
      -ms-box-orient: vertical;
      box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
      -moz-line-clamp: 5;
      -ms-line-clamp: 5;
      line-clamp: 5;
      overflow: hidden;
 }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div> hello,world!hello,world!hello,world!hello,world!hello,world!hello,world!hello,world!hello,world!hello,world!hello,world!hello,world!hello,world!hello,world!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Although -webkit-line-clamp works in this case. It is limited to 5 lines in this example. So make sure when you use it, the height is fixed and the line-height matches. For support across browsers see. [CSS-Tricks - line-clamp](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/). More answers are in this question [With CSS, use “…” for overflowed block of multi-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines)

Comment: some explanation about the css attributes might help

Comment: Unfortunately, applying padding throws this approach off. You can work around it by adding a container element and adding padding to the container.

Comment: not answering the question, since you are using a hard-coded `height` for this doctored example, and this solution will fail with any other `height` value

Comment: Be mindful of -webkit-line-clamp limitations, like the fixed number of lines (e.g., 5).
    Consider a container for padding to avoid disrupting truncation.
    Avoid hard-coding heights for flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think You need this try this one hopefully it is helpful for you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hide-long-text").each(function() {
    if (this.scrollHeight > $(this).height()) {
      $(this).addClass("overflowed");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-long-text {
  height: 80px;
  width: 110px;
  border: 1px solid #adb8c0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: normal; // Allow text to wrap
}

.hide-long-text .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;   //Number of lines to show 
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  height: 3em; //Height of 3 lines
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide-long-text" id="text-container">
  Now a long wooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooooooord
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently `-webkit-line-clamp` property only supports an integer number which represents the maximum number of lines to possibly render before truncating the text with an *ellipsis*.

[Until such support is baked into CSS](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/9368) - limiting truncated text to fit no more than its container's height, a javascript-based solution can simulate such support by utilizing a [technique of mine](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/BawdgEd) which counts how many lines of text can fit in a container.

A `ResizeObserver` observer updates the `--line-clamp` CSS variable by calling the `lineCount` function which measures how many lines of text can fit in the container.

✒️ [See my fancy Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/eYbGgGL)

```js
// get the DOM node parent (<div>) of the truncated container (<p>) 
const node = document.querySelector('div')

// helper method
const removeStyleProp = (node, props) => 
  node.style.cssText = node.style.cssText.split('; ') 
    .filter(sp => props.every(p => !sp.startsWith(p)) ) 
    .join(';');

// deals with editable content, where user can hit "ENTER" or "SHIFT+ENTER" 
// or complex content with nested block-level elements and <br>s
const addMeasureStyles = () => {
  document.head.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<style id="measureSingleLineHeight">
    .measureSingleLineHeight{ position: absolute !important; }
      .measureSingleLineHeight br{ display: none !important; }
      .measureSingleLineHeight *{ display: inline !important; }
  </style>`)  
}

// Get how manay lines of text can fit in 
// the DOM element (with a certain height)
function lineCount(node) { 
  const originalStyle = node.style.cssText
  const computedStyles = getComputedStyle(node)
  const isBorderBox = computedStyles['box-sizing'] == 'border-box'
  const boxVerticalPadding = ['padding-top', 'padding-bottom'].reduce((acc, p) => acc + parseInt(computedStyles[p]) , 0)
  let initialScrollHeight  // with original line-height & height
  let scrollHeight // with full normalization - "line-height:0 & "height:auto"

  // normalize (should probably be done to all children also via treeWalker)
  // if "box-sizing: border-box;" skip next steps (but do them later for measuring single-line height)
  if( !isBorderBox ){
    node.style.padding = 0 // clear restrains that might harm measuring
    node.style.border = 0 // clear restrains that might harm measuring
  }

  initialScrollHeight = node.clientHeight - (isBorderBox ? boxVerticalPadding : 0)

  addMeasureStyles()
  node.classList.add('measureSingleLineHeight')
  node.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap' // make the whole text a single line, to measure line-height
  node.style.height = 'auto' // make the height fit exactly to the single-line
  node.style.padding = 0 // clear restrains that might harm measuring
  node.style.border = 0 // clear restrains that might harm measuring

  const initialLineHeight = node.scrollHeight - 1; // fix inaccurate height

  node.style.minHeight = 0   // clear restrains that might harm measuring
  node.style.lineHeight = 1  // normalize line-height to fit the font perfectly

  // measure
  const singleLineHeight = node.scrollHeight  // easy with "white-space:nowrap"

  // cleanup
  measureSingleLineHeight.remove()
  node.classList.remove('measureSingleLineHeight')
  removeStyleProp(node, ['white-space', 'border', 'padding']); // bring back original border & padding because they affect the number of rendered lines (border-box)

  scrollHeight = node.scrollHeight - (isBorderBox ? boxVerticalPadding : 0)

  const lineCount = Math.round(scrollHeight / singleLineHeight)
  const linesFit = Math.floor(initialScrollHeight / initialLineHeight)

  // undo above style changes
  node.style.cssText = originalStyle

  return {
    lineCount: (isNaN(lineCount) || singleLineHeight == 0) ? 0 : lineCount,
    linesFit
  }
}

// Set DOM Observers:
//------------------------
function update(){
  const linesfit = lineCount(node)?.linesFit;
  linesfit && node.style.setProperty('--line-clamp', linesfit)
}

// observe resize
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(m => 
  node.clientWidth > 50 && requestAnimationFrame(update)
)

resizeObserver.observe(node, { attributes: true })

// observe content edits
const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(update);

// Start observing the target node for mutations
mutationObserver.observe(node, {characterData:true, childList:true, subtree:true});
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px dashed silver;
  resize: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: var(--line-clamp, 9999);
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p contenteditable>
    <em>Try resizing this area</em> container to see that the text will be trimmed if it exceeds the height of the container.
    <br><br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
  </p>
</div>
```