# How to spread text into multiple lines based on the height of a div and add an ellipsis at the end?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a long text that I want to display inside a div with a fixed width and height.

I have tried using the CSS properties:

```css
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

but this only displays the text on a single line.

I want to display the text on multiple lines that fit within the height of the div and add an ellipsis at the end if the text exceeds the available space. I have created a CodePen to demonstrate the issue: https://codepen.io/roee030/pen/bGYYjEr

Here is the CSS code I am using:

```css
.root {
  width: 283px;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 283px;
  background-color: coral;
}

.text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="title">
    asdasdasdasdasd
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
    you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary
    of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
  </div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't 1 line exactly what `nowrap` is supposed to do?

Comment: @Sven I want more than 1 line, to the whole box.

Comment: What I meant is, you have: `white-space: nowrap`. This line is causing your text to stay on 1 line. So I'm wondering why you have this line, if you do want your text to wrap.

Comment: @Sven it's because `white-space: nowrap` is a required when using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` which ellipsis is what OP wants, just not at the first line. It's impossible simply using only nowrap and ellipsis and still display multiple lines, but there are workarounds. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing those workarounds, very useful.

Comment: [csswg-drafts feature-request](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/9368)

Comment: Related to - https://stackoverflow.com/q/51816862/104380

Comment: Related to - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77134144/104380

Answer (score 2):

> The `text-overflow` property doesn't force an overflow to occur. To make `text-overflow` its container you have to set other CSS properties: [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) and [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

~ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

So in short, the behavior you are experiencing is standard with `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. `white-space: nowrap;` is required for ellipsis to take effect. (which is also putting the text on one line).

So let's look at **workarounds**:

You can nest your text in the [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) element with ***hidden*** and ***overflow*** styles. If you have a contained (fixed-height) on your parent element, you can specify a [`line-clamp`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/).

> The line-clamp property truncates text at a specific number of lines.

~ [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/)

---

So for example: If you have a parent with a `div` that has a fixed height of `283px` you can specify `-webkit-line-clamp: 13;` which produces 13 lines, corresponding with the height of the parent.

However, keep in mind that the `line-clamp` property works well with:

[`display: -webkit-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-flex)

[`-webkit-box-orient: vertical;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient)

```css
.root {
  width: 283px;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 283px;
  background-color: coral;
}

span {
  -webkit-line-clamp: 13;
  display: -webkit-box;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="title">
    asdasdasdasdasd
  </div>
  <div class="text"><span>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.<span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't really answers the question and is a reverse-logic solution, where you set a hard-coded `height` to the container based on the number of desired lines to show. A solution should work with any given `height` value, for example `276px`