# Css text-overflow not showing properly

Tags: whitespace, css

Can't get to show properly my `h2` title when to large

[image: preview]

CSS:

```
.column li{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 150px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    display: inline;
  }
  .column li .block {
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #ccc;

    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;

    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .column li .block a img {
    width: 89%;
    padding: 5%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background: white;
  }
  .column li .block h2{ font-size: 1.1em; margin: 10px 0 20px 0; border: 1px solid green; }
  .column li .block h2 a{ color: #000000; }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you define "show properly". I don't know what you consider "proper" for your site. Also, it's very hard to assess CSS rules without seeing the html they are acting on. Can you boil this down to a small working example of the problem (one that can be read easily by folks here in a few minutes)? If you do that and don't figure out the solution while you are doing it then you can provide the whole example here and we can help you troubleshoot it without wasting a lot of time deciphering unrelated elements.

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new today. I didn't even know the `ellipsis` option existed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'm guessing... Since the rule with `text-overflow: ellipsis` also has `height: 200px`, it's not the actual element that the text is in, but rather the bounding box with gray background.

`text-overflow` and `overflow` are *not inherited*, which means that if you want them to apply to the text, it must be defined on the element containing the text, not a parent element.

In other words:

```
.column li .block h2
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* <---- */
    overflow: hidden;        /* <---- */
    white-space: nowrap;     /* This one is inherited, but for consistency's 
                                sake, you may want to move it */
}
```

If you need a multiple line box with an ellipsis at the end of the last line, that's not currently possible without javascript. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404508/cross-browsers-mult-lines-text-overflow-with-ellipsis-appended-within-a-widthhe).

Comment: ok, it works but setting only the `text-overflow:...` is not enough I had to set also at least `overflow: hidden;` so the **...** show up.

Comment: @w0rldart - yeah, `overflow` also isn't inherited. `white-space` is, but for consistency's sake, you should probably move that too. Updated answer.

Comment: now the problem is that everything limits to only 1 line of text. I would like to set it a max text/width/characters and then show the ellipsis. I've tried already with width/height and max but no succes

Comment: @w0rldart - Added link to a question dealing with multiple lines.

Comment: so it all ends to jquery :). Thanks for the info @TheKaneda. I'll mark your answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `white-space:nowrap;` if you want the text in the green box displayed on several lines.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `.column li` to `display: block`. It already floats, so there is no `display: inline` needed. And `text-overflow` is not inherited, as already mentioned.

Also it depends on the browser, not all support `ellipsis`. Look [here](http://caniuse.com/text-overflow) for more information.