# jquery compare the height beneath img to h2's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, while-loop, each

I am trying to adapt this:

```
var h2=$('.block h2');
var divh=$('.block').height();
while ($(h2).outerHeight()>divh) {
    alert('enters while');
    $(h2).text(function (index, text) {
        return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
    });
}
```

as explained here: [Cross browsers mult-lines text overflow with ellipsis appended within a width&height fixed div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404508/cross-browsers-mult-lines-text-overflow-with-ellipsis-appended-within-a-widthhe)

The problem I have encountered in my case is that I have various `li` where each one contains a `.block` which has a `h2` tag per `li`

Example:

```
<li>
<div class="block">
....
<h2>Tittleasfasjgpashgj9ahgpasgnapsighapighapsogna</h2>
...
</div>
</li>

<li>
<div class="block">
....
<h2>5Tittleasfasjgpashgj9ahgpasgnapsighapighapsogna</h2>
...
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI82f.jpg

<strike>Having `.block` set with 200px, inside having `img` set to `height: 90px;` and a `padding: 5px` now I need to take the height left beneath img and compare to `h2`'s height.</strike>

But it doesn't work either, it just doesn't do the if, but `divh` contains data (200, the 200px set in css).

Edit:

So I just figure out that the best way to fix this is to set a height to `h2` tag and than compare its content height with the set one.

Comment: Did you mean `$('h2')` on line 3,5 ?

Comment: You are missing a `(` after the `while`, but I don't know if your code will work exactly if this is all you have as `$h2` isn't defined in this portion.

Comment: sorry, it's `var h2=...` not `var p` and added the `(`

Comment: try adding alert($(this).outerHeight()) before the if, to verify the value you expect.

Comment: now I get it why it doesn't work... it never returns a value higher than 200. Pfff

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work fine:

```
$('.block').each(function (i, el) {
    var $h2 = $(el).find('h2');
    var divh = $(el).height();
    while ($h2.outerHeight() > divh) {
        $h2.text(function (index, text) {
           return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
        });
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k5VET/1/)

You should use `.block { word-wrap: break-word; }` (or put some spaces into those long h2 texts) to let them break and help the effect happen.

*As I also stated in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404508/cross-browsers-mult-lines-text-overflow-with-ellipsis-appended-within-a-widthhe/3880955), this is just an idea, not something ready to be used in production. It is quite DOM-heavy and may not be the best solution for all use cases.*

Comment: the problem is that `.block` is set to 200px height and h2 returns at most 60 so I have to reduce the 200 with the image height and what is left if bigger than it than do the replacing, right?

Comment: can you suggest any better solution?

Comment: @w0rldart The problem is that I don't really understand the problem :). Could you illustrate it with a jsFiddle? The idea depends on a wrapper (`#fos` in the original) around the element (`p` in the original). The only job of the wrapper should be to include the element and define its height.

Comment: @w0rldart I did not really have a chance to see your code and what you want to achieve exactly, but I'm happy you've solved it. You should answer your question, describe your solution and accept it.

Comment: will do @bazmegakapa... Thank you for your help also

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're regex only works for space separated words. Long strings like you have won't be shortened.

Secondly, you dont need to use another selector on your h2 var in the while condition.

Thirdly, the .each is definitely required.

```
var h2=$('.block h2');
h2.each(function(){
    var divh=$(this).closest('.block').height();
    while ($(this).outerHeight()>divh) {
        $(h2).text(function (index, text) {
            return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
        });
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/LUP4s/)

Comment: This will use the height of the first block for all elements, which is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may have a couple of problems, first you have a typo on the "while" line where I think you really want to do

```
while ($('h2').outerHeight()>divh) {
```

But really I think you want to use the .each() jquery method, something like

```
$('h2').each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).outerHeight() > divh) {
    //...
  }
});
```

Comment: Using `each` there totally breaks the logic itself :).

Comment: how's that? he want's to iterate over the h2 tags, the .each() will do that, no? Yes, I do see that there should be an outer loop to get the height of each .block.

Comment: @creechy He needs to iterate with `each()` in this scenario, but the `while` should remain in place because it is the heart of the solution.