# Block level equivalent of text-overflow:ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I want to offer small blurbs that will disappear into ellipsis if they are too long for the container div they are put into. I would like to offer a visual indication that there is more text if a user follows the link to the article. I don't want to use an ellipse image, but I can use jQuery if required. My preference is to do it entirely in CSS3, if possible.

I found the text-overflow:ellipsis property / value, combined with overflow:hidden and white-space:nowrap allow for a single-line version of this, but what about multi-lines?  vs.  in my case.

Will these, or another property / value pair allow for this to be done in strictly CSS?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On what criteria do you want the overflow to appear?

Comment: do you want every line of text to finish with an ellipsis?, so render a paragaph, but clip it?

Comment: Multiline isn't supported. You will need javascript to support this. See question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines)

Comment: Sounds a bit like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404508/cross-browsers-mult-lines-text-overflow-with-ellipsis-appended-within-a-widthhe

Comment: paragraph tag is in-line, not block. I need multi-lines ending in ellipsis.

Comment: Should I use a paragraph for a div this small? I was planning on just using a `<div id="wrapper" class="ellipsis">Enjoy this other stuff that I have enticed you to read based on other items you seem to have enjoyed</div>`. I would expect this to render out as : **Enjoy this other stuff that I have enticed you to read based on other items you seem...** without the need for paragraphs inside the div. Bad form? Bad practice?

Comment: multiline is supported, it bc of the white-space:nowrap in the css alongside having no height on the overflow:hidden div

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert ellipsis (...) into HTML tag if content too wide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5VET/) *not mine*

or there is the [dotdotdot plugin](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/)

Comment: The dotdotdot plugin satisfies this question - and it works. Now if I can get it to expand vertically as well as horizontally it would be perfect. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Given HTML mark-up along the following lines:

```
<div class="multiline"><!-- long string of text... --></div>

<div class="singleline"><!-- long string of text... --></div>​
```

And the following CSS:

```
div {
    /* aesthetic stuff, such as width, max-width, border, line-height etc... */
    overflow: hidden; /* required to hide the overflow */
    position: relative;  /* required to position the pseudo-element */
}
div.multiline {
    max-height: 12em; /* defines the 'overflow point' */
}
div.singleline {
    max-height: 1.5em;
}
div::after {
    content: '...';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QBjKs/).

While this broadly achieves your intent, in compliant browsers, it does have the problem of not lining up the generated 'ellipsis' with the end of the visible text, unfortunately.

Comment: This works, but it also puts ellipsis unconditionally, even when the text doesn't overflow. Text doesn't always overflow for these. But, yes, this is a very good solution for non-conditional versions of this problem.

Comment: @JonMitten - With all due respect, it's not a good solution, **at all**. I'm sure David did his best here, but the famous celebrity that is CSS3, `<sarcasm>` is so good that it doesn't need to be flexible `</sarcasm>`.

Answer (score 0):

remove css

```
 white-space:nowrap;
```

and set a height to your div

Comment: Set a height, or a max-height?

Comment: to prove the point, try height for now .. the main problem ( only 1 line of text) was due to white-space:nowrap; - the height is set because you need 'something' when you have overflow:hidden.