# jQuery and dotdotdot for Truncating Table Cells

Tags: jquery, html-table

I know very little about Javascript and jQuery, and I'm attempting to use jQuery and the [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) plugin to truncate TDs in a table *after the second wrapped line*.

I figure I'll never learn without asking;

A. Is this even possible?

B. How would I achieve this with dotdotdot -or- is there a better way?

The image in this other question ([Cross-browser multi-line text overflow with ellipsis appended within a width and height fixed `<div>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404508/)) is exactly what I want to happen, but I can't figure out how to adapt it for use in table cells. Without knowing Javascript, jQuery seemed the best suited to do what I had in mind.

Comment: Do you just want to truncate the text at a certain character count without a readmore button?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That could work, provided it still wraps however many lines to fill the specified height of the TD element.

Comment: [Does this emulate the intended functionality?](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/Bk5Uq/), [Or maybe you want to have vastly more characters allowed?](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/Bk5Uq/1/)

Comment: This might just do the trick!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Hm, except that it seems to be appending the ellipsis to every TD, including empty ones.

Comment: Sorry, I just took a guess at your needs. Can you tell me what the relationship should be? do you just want to avoid empty TD's?

Comment: Thus far, it looks like it'll do what I'm looking for. If it could skip empty cells and cells that are already < the max number of characters, it'd be prefect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, skips empty cells, doesn't apply to cells with less than the defined max char count.

```
$(function(){
  $.each($('td').not(':empty'), function(i,v){
    var count = parseInt($(v).text().length);
    var maxChars = 210;
    if(count > maxChars){
      var str = $(v).text();
      var trimmed = str.substr(0, maxChars - 2);
      $(v).text(trimmed + '...');          
    }  
  });
});
```

*+1 for CraftyFella's comment*

[Here's the working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/Bk5Uq/4/)

Comment: You'd want var trimmed = str.substr(0, maxChars - 2); to keep it at 210 chars wouldn't you?

Comment: Looks good! I am immensely thankful for your help. Thanks again!

Comment: +1 I like the length of string usage to specify when the ellipsis should be added rather than a set with of the td.

Comment: @CraftyFella you're completely right. I had gone devoid of thought, thank you. :)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I came across this issue recently.  My issue is that I'm using this in a table with pagination - on initial page load, everything works great.  But if I "paginate" to the next set of results the max character styling with "..." goes away.

Comment: @Michael The issue is that JavaScript doesn't inherently observe changes to the document. This would require either a Mutation Observer, or to put that method into the a function and call the function after the pagination completes (which I assume is an AJAX driven response)

Answer (score 1):

Can you check this jsFiddle out, it does not use jQuery because from what I understand from your question you need to know how to make the ellipsis, which is do-able with css rather than needing jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/xjLA7/1/

if you need it to be done via a script please tell me how you want this achieved and I will play a little more, but I hope this is what you need to make your td's overflow with the ellipsis rather than extending the td.

Here is my source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
td.test div
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="test">
            <div>This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>​
```

Regards.

Comment: Ahhh I have re-read your question and see you want ellipsis to be applied more intelligently. I will leave my answer so that the basic css can be seen but I can see it is not skipping the td as in Ohgodwhy's answer and ellipsis are added indiscriminately rather than after the first line or to a set length of chars.

Answer (score 0):

dotdotdot does not work properly when called directly on a `td` element.  You have to create a `div` inside the `td` element, put your content in the `div`, specify a max width/height for the `td` element, and call dotdotdot on the `div`.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Short Column</th>
    <th>Long Column</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Some info</td>
    <td height=50px width=50px>
        <div id='long-column'><p>This is a long column that should be truncated by the dotdotdot plugin.</p></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#long-column').dotdotdot({});
    });
</script>
```

See this fiddle for a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/q3wdqtw5/