# CSS word ellipsis ('...') after one or two lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, ellipsis

I'm trying to create a word-wrap in JavaScript using CSS, and the condition is:

If DIV contains one *very* long word, such as *"asdasfljashglajksgkjasghklajsghl"*, I want to display:

```
     |asdasfljashglajk...|
```

If DIV contains a long sentence, such as *"if i had a dime for everytime i was told i can't"*, I want to display:

```
     |if i had a dime for|
     |everytime i was... |
```

I work with HTML, CSS, JavaScript. I can't use jQuery.

Please let me know if it's possible.

Comment: Can you define what "long word" and "long sentence" mean to you exactly? (A number of characters, a certain width...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross browsers mult-lines text overflow with ellipsis appended within a width&height fixed div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404508/cross-browsers-mult-lines-text-overflow-with-ellipsis-appended-within-a-widthhe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this you can use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property. Write like this

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: This will work for the first case (ellipsis on long word), but not the second (ellipsis on second line)

Comment: The second case is not simple with css only, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404508/cross-browsers-mult-lines-text-overflow-with-ellipsis-appended-within-a-widthhe

Comment: yea for multiple lines,javascript is the solution

Comment: thanks, i managed to create the ellipsis for 2 lines, and i managed to create for one line.  is there a way, with JS or html css, to get them both? i mean, if there's one long word(the length can be set) then "..." appears in the same row, and if there are many words, the "..." appears in the second line? thanks again

Comment: may also need overflow: hidden in some cases.

Comment: Why is this selected solution when it does not solve the problem of having two+ lines of text?

Answer (score 9):

Found this:

http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp

Looks like `-webkit-line-clamp` works in some browsers.

Comment: awesome , big like, helped me a lot

Answer (score 7):

I know I'm a bit late with the anwser but I just wrote a pice of code that accomplices that:

```
    if ($('your selector').height() > 50) {
        var words = $('your selector').html().split(/\s+/);
        words.push('...');

        do {
            words.splice(-2, 1);
            $('your selector').html( words.join(' ') );
        } while($('your selector').height() > 50);
    }
```

and of course you should save the jQuery selector in a variable so you don't query the DOM every time.

Comment: Didn't OP say `I can't use jQuery`?

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, with CSS alone I don't think you can.

http://jsfiddle.net/TVVHs/

`text-overflow: ellipsis;` *only* works with `white-space: nowrap;` which prevents multiple lines.

There probably is a crazy javascript solution that keeps chopping off words until the element height is acceptable, but that will be slow and pretty damn hacky nasty.

Comment: As for the slowness of the JavaScript solution, it could be made faster by doing a *binary* search for the maximum number of words that fits in the desired height, instead of a linear search. For example, start with half the words, and then if that's too tall, try a quarter of the words, and if that all fits, try 3/8 of the words, etc.

Answer (score 3):

when you'll be allowed to use jQuery you could see the dotdotdot plugin at [this link](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).. very simple to use and it works great!

For the moment i can suggest you to have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5VET/)! whould work the `text-overflow: ellipsis`

Comment: sry.. i've lately noticed that @Luca already linked the discussion i took the fiddle from!

Answer (score 3):

After fiddling around with the CSS to come up with a "next-best" CSS ONLY solution, I came up with this:

```
p.excerpt { position: relative; height: 63px; line-height: 21px; overflow-y: hidden; }
p.excerpt:after { content: '...'; position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

This would always assume you have at least 3 lines of text, and there are a couple of issues with it.  If the last word to wrap onto line 4 is very long, there would be an unusually large blank space between the last word and the ellipsis.  Similarly, it could overlap the last word if it was something very, *very* small, like "a".

You could add another container and have the ellipsis outside of the `p`, and with a bit of comment tweaking I'm sure someone will fiddle up something better.

Comment: This really helped me a lot!!
I just added an additional css class for empty cells, so that they would not show the "..." when there is no more text to show
p.excerpt:empty { height: 0; line-height: 0; }

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee the content will run over, here is the solution I came up. It works for my site and I wanted to keep it simple.

html:

```
<p class="snippet">
   [content]
</p>
```

css:

```
.snippet {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px; // for 2 lines
    font-size: 14px; // standard site text-size
    line-height: 1.42857; // standard site line-height
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.news-insights .snippet:after {
    content: "\02026";
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 20%, white); // use vendor prefixes for production code
}
```

You can then play around with the padding and background gradient to get a more stylish presentation.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this answers your question

```
  @mixin multilineEllipsis(
  $lines-to-show: 2,
  $width: 100%,
  $font-size: $fontSize-base,
  $line-height: 1.6) {

  display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: $width;
  height: $font-size * $line-height * $lines-to-show; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  font-size: $font-size;
  -webkit-line-clamp: $lines-to-show;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp
http://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-line-clamp

Comment: Why is this answer not popular?  It works as long the text is longer than the width set. you can create a generic width and height and will get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying the ellipsis needs to be handled differently when the width of container is fixed and percentage.

- When width of container is fixed

```css
    .nooverflow{
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-wrap: normal;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

- When width of container is in percentage or auto, in this scenario define another tag in that container to render the text and specify width as 0 and min-width as 100%, that way it will take the width of container and show the ellipsis. Below is the LESS class to be used:

```css
    .nooverflow{
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden!important;
        overflow-wrap: normal;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap!important;
        width: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
```