# how to add ellipsis in column of table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am trying to add ellipsis in column .I am using ionic framework with angular js .I am displaying data in column .But when data is more than 2 or two line it should show "..." or ellipsis .I google it found this solution

[CSS word ellipsis ('...') after one or two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665229/css-word-ellipsis-after-one-or-two-lines)

but it will not work the I found another solution this
http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp .it also not work for me

here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/BILpSThKHWZpKBqYIoQz?p=preview

```
.columnClass {

  margin: 0 auto;

  line-height: $line-height;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

any update regarding this

Comment: I think it only works if you put `white-space:nowrap;`, but you can't achieve multiline purpose with this. I will research right now for a solution.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGWeNq

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js

It adds compatibility for non-webkit browsers. I wish you solve the problem.
The use:

```
$clamp(myHeader, {clamp: 3}); // 3 lines
$clamp(myParagraph, {clamp: "25px"}); // 25 pixels
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Why? If you hate some plugins that you don't want to use, please, list it and we provide your custom solution