# Is css3 line clamp possible in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

Currently to limit a text box vertically, and add ellipsis, there only is a webkit css3 solution using line-clamp & box-orient.

Demo (safari or chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/ArKeu/136/

Now this is not supported anywhere else, not even using prefixes. So my question is if it is possible to do this easily in pure javascript. In short, let a sentence flow on multiple lines and add stop it after a couple while adding ellipsis.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [With CSS, use "..." for overflowed block of multi-lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404508/cross-browsers-mult-lines-text-overflow-with-ellipsis-appended-within-a-widthhe

Comment: yes but that is all jQuery :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I modified the code form [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3880955/219118) to be pure-JS. You don't specify the number of lines, but the height of the box. You can easily calculate height from number of lines by multiplying number of lines by `line-height`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="fos">
    <p>text here</p>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var container = document.getElementById("fos");
var containerHeight = container.clientHeight;
var para = container.children[0];

while (para.clientHeight > containerHeight) {
    para.innerText = para.innerText.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5VET/382/)

Comment: be careful that some languages don't use space character to separate words

Comment: you saved my day!