# Adapting @bazmegakapa's Ellipsis Script for Inline Use

Tags: javascript, jquery, inline, ellipsis, css

SO,

I'm working on adapting @bazmegakapa's script (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3880955/1592764)) to work using inline  tags:

```
<script type="javascript">
var p=$('#fos p');
var divh=$('#fos').height();
while ($(p).outerHeight()>divh) {
$(p).text(function (index, text) {
    return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
});
}
</script>
```

The code (which I've commented out in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/EqPc6/7/)) works great until it's placed inside the  tags. Any ideas on what could be causing the breakdown? I think @bazmegakapa's script is brilliant, mainly because it's so much shorter and more manageable than other ellipsis plugins out there, and I'd love to figure out how to get over this hurdle and actually implement it in my project. I'm still very much a javascript novice so help from the guys at SO would be great.

-Marcatectura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, I'm almost positive it's because of how you're expecting things done in a fiddle. You currently have the fiddle's Javascript to be run `onLoad`, which means the DOM will be ready by that point. In your case of **inline** Javascript, you have it printed in the HTML **above** the elements that are targeted. HTML is parsed from top to bottom, so the script is run before the elements are even known. When you try to manipulate things that don't "exist" yet, it won't work. So you either need to put your **inline** script **below** your main HTML, or use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Your code here
});
```

anywhere on the page.

It might've helped to check your browser's console, but things might not have failed in your situation because jQuery doesn't bomb if elements aren't found - it'll just return correct things, like undefined possibly, so that your other logic would probably fail...just not bomb. Javascript would bomb if you tried `document.getElementById("asdf").value` if there was no element with an `id` of "asdf". But it wouldn't bomb if you used `$("#asdf").val()` - it would just returned undefined or something.

Quick note: you don't need to wrap `p` like `$(p)` - it's already a jQuery object, so you can call jQuery methods on plain `p`.

UPDATE:

It seemed like the problem was the fact that the `<script>` tag needed to have the type "text/javascript", not just "javascript". Here's the fiddle that has your working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z47CX/3/

Comment: Your problem is the script tag - it needs to be `type="text/javascript"`. Among other debugging help, here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z47CX/3/

Comment: @mplungjan Haha no worries, so it's doing what you need now?

Comment: Not my script just wanted to test YOUR suggestions in a fiddle. You need to update your answer with the mime type error

Comment: @ianpgall your fiddle did the trick...you should repost as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: @Marcatectura I just updated my answer with the explanation. The problem was both the location of your script and the `type` attribute, so this answer contains all that information.