# Fit text inside div

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can i fit a large amount text a fixed size div.? i want when reach text maximum width of this div then break text with dots...

i tried this, i dont see the result really what i want

```
.description {
  max-width:590px;
  max-height:100px;
  float:left;
}
```

[image: result what i got now]

[image]

i want like this image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give it a fixed width and use `text-overflow` CSS property width a value `ellipsis`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MBdBk/)

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Note: This will be effective only for a single line

If you want this should work on a multiple line, then you need to use jQuery

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXY4R/)([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404508/cross-browsers-mult-lines-text-overflow-with-ellipsis-appended-within-a-widthhe))

Comment: your example its working a single line, if div width 400px; height 100px;  how to fit.?

Answer (score 1):

use `text-overflow` properties

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

and you should keep.

```
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
```

Here is a reference to use overflow content.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Dc7UA/)

Here is a jquery plugin that handle multiple lines of text. One that seems to work is: http://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/VpmbL/

Comment: This works, but he asked for multiple lines of text in a div not a single line in a list-item