# Show first 3 lines in HTML paragraph

Tags: html, css

I want to show only the first 3 lines of the paragraph below using HTML formatting. I am searching on W3Schools but it doesn't show how to do it.

```
<body>

loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlor
loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore
loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore
loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore
loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore

</body>
```

Comment: The answer you've accepted **wrong** (it has no `overflow` specified so wouldn't hide anything), it would show 4 lines rather than 3 if it did. Why on earth was that marked as the correct answer?

Comment: don't use the w3school website , it harms the education , see w3fools.com

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404508/cross-browsers-mult-lines-text-overflow-with-ellipsis-appended-within-a-widthhe

Answer (score 21):

You can give the container a `height` and `line-height` and set its `overflow` property to `hidden`:

**HTML**

```
<p>loremloremlorem...</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    height:60px;
    line-height:20px; /* Height / no. of lines to display */
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zC3rd/1).

Answer (score 16):

Set the height of the paragraph to three line-heigths. Like -

```
p{
  line-height:1.2em;
  height:3.6em;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Set overflow to hidden to hide overflowing text

Comment: However, `line-height` should normally be set to a value larger than `1em`, e.g. `1.2em`. That’s normal typography, for readability.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`-webkit-line-clamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp) property with `div`.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height: 3.6em;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
}
```

```html
<div>
  loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore
  loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore
  loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore
  loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore
  loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<p>
  loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlor loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore
  loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlore
</p>
```

Comment: Please fully explain your answer and don't just dump a block of code, expecting that everyone will understand what you did. Thanks