# Getting font css property does not work in IE and Firefox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I try to get the whole font style of an element with IE or Firefox with the following code I only get a empty result, but with Chrome and Opera I get `"normal normal bold normal 20px/normal arial"` as I would have expected.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="test" style="font: bold 20px arial; color: red;">test</div>

// JS
alert($('#test').css('font'));
```

Wyh does this happen and how do I get the complete font property otherwise?

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/mwj12xkv/

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664759/jquery-how-to-get-assigned-font-to-element

Comment: You may try to use `$('#test').attr('style')`, then crop the style that belong to `font`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to query the individual `font-*` properties you're interested in. From [the `css` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., `margin`, `background`, `border`), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered `border-width`, use: `$( elem ).css( "borderTopWidth" )`, `$( elem ).css( "borderBottomWidth" )`, and so on.