# Coloring text in Rich textbox based on type of its font in C#

Tags: c#, fonts, colors

I need some help i need to color the text in rich text-box based on font type like if a string has "Times new roman" while other has "comics font " than both need to be color differently.Can any one help me out,I try to find some solution but most of them related to the coloring text "NOT"based on font.

Answer (score 0):

Now after understanding your question correctly, here is the solution:

Created RichTextBox control on the form:

`rtb1`

Following code should serve the purpose:

```
// Coloring on the basis of font
int boxLength = rtb1.TextLength;
int i = 0;
while (i < boxLength)
{
    rtb1.Select(i, 1);
    switch (rtb1.SelectionFont.Name)
    {
        case "Courier New": rtb1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            break;
        case "Times New Roman": rtb1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
            break;
        default: rtb1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
            break;
    }


    i++;
}
```

**To Test:**

Paste random font from MS Word as follows

**Before execution of code**

[image: Before execution of code]

**After execution of code**

[image: After execution of code]

Is this what is required?

Comment: ,Aneja Thanks for the reply ...it gave me a great idea to solve my problem thanks...

Comment: @Tenzin Great!! Please upvote if it solved your issue.. Also chose as your answer

Comment: @Aaneja ---my problem is to find the text of particular font family type from 1000 pages of text and then replace them with new text your solution is good but it took lot of time so .....any idea how to solve it using regular-expression like finding my  font type using regular expression or some other  fast way...

Comment: @TenzinJinpa Can you explain how are that 1000 pages implemented on the form? Is it one single RichTextBox? I would like to understand the scenario so that I can come up with some better algorithm.

Comment: @Aaneja---Iam using rich textbox for taking input now what iam doing is that 1)I am changing the large textfile that i had open in rich textbox 2)the text is not using unicode and so we need to convert all the text into a unicode format 3)I had success in converting it to unicode but time it took for 1000 page book or text is too large...

Comment: for (i = 0; i <= richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = i;
                richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 1;
                FontFamily ff = richTextBox1.SelectionFont.FontFamily;
                if (ff.Name.Equals("LTibetan"))
                {

Comment: richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                    char[] array1 = richTextBox1.SelectedText.ToCharArray();
                    foreach (char a in array1)
                    {string a1 = a.ToString();
                        string temp2 = (string)hashtable[a1];
                        temp3 = temp3 + temp2;
                        richTextBox2.Text = temp3;

Comment: @Aaneja--above are the code snapshot can you suggest any alternative solutions

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, since you don't mention where you want to test. You could follow this link [obtaining font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664759/jquery-how-to-get-assigned-font-to-element) that shows how to get the font in JQuery and then you can just decorate the css with your desired colour.