# How to expand truncated text onclick by using dotdotdot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotdotdot

I am using the `jQuery dotdotdot` truncation plugin [dotdotdot.frebsite.nl](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl)

I want to truncate at max 2 lines. And when a user clicks on `more`, then it must show the full text (expand/de-truncate).

So far, I "only" manage to truncate my text. But not to "de-truncate" it.

Here is my code:

```
<p class="truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vitae tellus eu dui placerat interdum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<a class="read-more" href="#">more</a></p>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.truncate').dotdotdot({
        ellipsis     : '… ',
        watch        : true,
        wrap         : 'letter',
        height       : parseInt( $('.truncate').css('line-height'), 10) * 2, // this is the number of lines
        lastCharacter: {
            remove: [ ' ', ',', ';', '.', '!', '?' ],
            noEllipsis: []
        },
        after: "a.read-more"
    });


});
```

Live demo [jsfiddle.net/NSnxe/1](http://jsfiddle.net/NSnxe/1/)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When a user clicks "more," I want the full text to expand and 'de-truncate'.

Comment: Note that the values you have for `lastCharacter` option are the same as the default ones. Hence this part of the code is irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read More and Read Less with dotdotdot jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187774/read-more-and-read-less-with-dotdotdot-jquery)

Comment: I added a complete answer to the same question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187774/read-more-and-read-less-with-dotdotdot-jquery/29118739#29118739

Answer (score 6):

You can send a destroy message to dotdotdot

```
$('a.read-more').on( 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().trigger("destroy");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/C5Ent/

Comment: @JoeAtzberger - I don't have 32, but it seems to be working fine in 33.  What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Ah, I take it back.  Must have just been my browser or my brain.  Looks fine now.

Comment: Does not work: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dotdotdot is not a function`

Comment: @izogfif - this plugin has changed significantly since 2013 and the dotdotdot.js file doesn't exist at it's previous location anymore.  I suggest looking at https://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl for it's current usage