# adding ellipsis using height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add ellipsis on multiline using javascript with [the below code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3880955/901048). It is working for most of the cases except for one case where the text width is the same as the width of the cell. I wasn't able to not add ellipsis in that case. So I need to check the width as well.

```
while ($(this).height() > 60) {
  $(this).text(function (index, text) {
    return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `CSS` instead? It's way easier.

Comment: Curious why you're not using CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis` instead.

Comment: @MelanciaUK CSS only works with a single line of text.

Comment: I guess I can't really understand what are the special needs here. Maybe an image will help

Comment: Can you try `while ($(this).height() >= 60) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try a container with overflow:hidden to add an ellipsis to an innner paragraph tag that overflows.

```
var $container = $(container);
    var $p = $container.find("p");
    var divh = $container.height();

    while ($p.outerHeight()>divh) {
        $p.text(function (index, text) {
            return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
         });
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply..i am using overflow:hidden only. But the issue is the last visible line doesnt have the ellipsis when the text overflows if the last visible line is equal to the width of the column.

Comment: last word is cut off and ellipsis is not visible

Comment: I don't understand your issue, is it up somewhere I could see it?