# add elipsis when multiple lines overflow on several div elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add execute this code which adds an elipsis at the end of the text when it overflows:

```
 var ph=$('.txt-entries .txt-entries-wrap');
                var p=$('.txt-entries .txt-entries-wrap p');
                var divh=$('.txt-entries').height();
                while ($(ph).outerHeight()>divh) {
                    $(p).text(function (index, text) {
                        return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
                    });
                }
```

adapted from this thread [Cross browsers mult-lines text overflow with ellipsis appended within a width&height fixed div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404508/cross-browsers-mult-lines-text-overflow-with-ellipsis-appended-within-a-widthhe)

To several div elements, but when I place it within an each loop it causes it to crash. Here is the **HTML**:

```
 <div class="txt-block">
                          <div class="txt-entries">
                                <div class="txt-entries-wrap">
                                    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                                    <p class="copy">Lorem ipsum</p>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                                <div class="cta-aligner">
                                    <a class="cta-2" href="#">
                                        Lorem ipsum
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
<div class="txt-block">
                          <div class="txt-entries">
                                <div class="txt-entries-wrap">
                                    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                                    <p class="copy">Lorem ipsum</p>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                                <div class="cta-aligner">
                                    <a class="cta-2" href="#">
                                        Lorem ipsum
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
```

How can I execute it for all `.txt-block` elements?

Comment: Update your jQuery selector to be less specific?

Comment: [This may be helpful](http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp)

Comment: that doesn't work pete