# "Smart" overflow in HTML: is there any way to put ellipsis "..." with a link at the end to view entire content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<div>` of constrained size, and I want to put multiline text in it, but if it's going to overflow, I'd like to put a "..." at the end with a link to view the entire content on another page.

Is this doable in Javascript/CSS? I tried searching a bit but I'm not sure what to look for.

Hmm -- looks like there's a CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis;` but I don't think I can put a link on the ellipsis.

---

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17187394/44330) is really close but there are cases where if it just starts to overflow then only part of the ellipsis shows up.

---

library requirements: I can use jQuery (somewhat reluctantly), would prefer a no-framework-dependency cross-browser solution.

Comment: You could get it with ellipsis css. I am still not exactly clear about question.

Comment: are you using a javascript framework? If so which?

Comment: Something like this? Here is a rough example.. https://jsfiddle.net/zh3bxme3/

Comment: @JoshCrozier its great solution. Could you explain a bit on JSFiddle with comments? I believe this addresses Jason's problem

Comment: @JoshCrozier Oh, that's clever. Put as an answer and explain how it works, and I'll accept.

Comment: hmm... and the ellipses + `<a>`  link would go away if there's no overflow?

Comment: You can also use your own text with text overflow in case "..." is not quite to your liking, for example: `text-overflow: "...(more)...";`

Comment: crap -- the `nowrap` kills it, I need multiline.

Comment: @pratikwebdev Thanks, I added it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160687/insert-ellipsis-after-specific-number-of-lines/29161423#29161423.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a basic example that iterates over elements with a class of `.smart-overflow`. It adds a clickable `a` element with a class of `ellipsis-link` *only* if the content is clipped. The link has a click event listener that will reveal the hidden content that was hidden with `overflow: hidden`. This example only works for a single line. See the alternative example below for an approach that works for multiple lines in supported browsers.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.smart-overflow');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (el) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = '#'; link.className = 'ellipsis-link';
  
  if (el.offsetWidth < el.scrollWidth) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      el.classList.remove('smart-overflow');
    });
    el.appendChild(link);
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.smart-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
a.ellipsis-link {
  display: none;
}
.smart-overflow a.ellipsis-link {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p class="smart-overflow">No ellipsis.</p>
<p class="smart-overflow">This is a longer string of text which should have ellipsis. This is a longer string of text which should have ellipsis.</p>
<p class="smart-overflow">Another string of text which should have ellipsis. Another string of text which should have ellipsis.</p>
```

In the example above, `text-overflow: ellipsis` requires `white-space: nowrap` in order to work which means that it only works for a single line.

If you want support for multiple lines, you can do something like this in supported browsers. If that doesn't work, see the jQuery solution below for full browser support.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.smart-overflow');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (el) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = '#'; link.className = 'ellipsis-link';

  link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    el.classList.remove('smart-overflow');
  });
  el.appendChild(link);
});
```

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.smart-overflow {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  max-height: 2.2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
a.ellipsis-link {
  display: none;
}
.smart-overflow a.ellipsis-link {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 4.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p class="smart-overflow">No ellipsis.</p>
<p class="smart-overflow">This is a longer multi-line string of text which should have ellipsis. This is a longer string of text which should have ellipsis.</p>
<p class="smart-overflow">Another multi-line string of text which should have ellipsis. Another multi-line string of text which should have ellipsis.</p>
```

jQuery multi-line alternative with full browser support using [this library](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).

```js
$('.smart-overflow').dotdotdot({
  ellipsis: '',
  wrap: 'word',
  callback: function(isTruncated, content) {
    var self = this;

    if (isTruncated) {
      $(this).append($('<a/>', {
        class: 'ellipsis-link',
        text: '...',
        href: '#',
        click: function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).remove();
          $(self).removeClass('smart-overflow is-truncated').trigger("destroy");
        }
      }));
    }
  }
});
```

```css
p { width: 200px; }
.smart-overflow { max-height: 2.8em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.dotdotdot/1.7.4/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js"></script>
<p class="smart-overflow">No ellipsis.</p>
<p class="smart-overflow">This is a longer multi-line string of text which should have ellipsis. This is a longer string of text which should have ellipsis.</p>
<p class="smart-overflow">Another multi-line string of text which should have ellipsis. Another multi-line string of text which should have ellipsis.</p>
```

Comment: which browsers support the `-webkit` stuff?

Comment: @JasonS Sadly only Chrome/Safari. After searching around, it looks like there is a clamp.js library that adds support -> https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js

Comment: yeah, I just ran across that too, going to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these jQuery plugins:

https://github.com/jjenzz/jquery.ellipsis
https://github.com/rviscomi/trunk8

Here's some code I wrote awhile back, that wraps trunk8, to make the ellipsis in to links and to make them responsive as well.

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

  'use strict';

  window.seeMore = function() {
    function addSeeMoreLinks() {
      $article.find('p').trunk8(options).each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (0 === $this.find('.trunk8').length) {
          $this.append(' <a href="#" class="seeMore">see more</a>.');
        }
      });
    }

    function removeSeeMoreLinks() {
      $article.find('p').each(function() {
        $(this).find('.seeMore').remove();
      });
    }

    function setupSeeMoreLinks() {
      addSeeMoreLinks();
      $(window).resize(function() {
        removeSeeMoreLinks();
        addSeeMoreLinks();
      });
    }

    var
      $article = $('.blogArticleList article'),
      options = {
        lines: 6,
        fill: '&hellip; <a href="#" class="trunk8">see more</a>.',
        tooltip: false
      };

    setupSeeMoreLinks();
  };

  if (window.addEventListener && $().trunk8) {
    window.seeMore();
  }

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to support a link on the `...` (or at least the docs don't mention it)

Comment: Just updated answer with some code I wrote last year to extend the trunk8 jquery plugin to do what I'm guessing you want to do. It also make the ellipses responsive.