# Angular multi-line ellipsis with conditional more link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I need a multi-line ellipsis angular directive where I can have ellipsis after x lines and display More/Less link conditionally only if the text is more than x lines.

below is my directive

```
 angular.module('app')
        .directive('expandableDivContent', expandableDivContent);

    expandableDivContent.$inject = ['$timeout', 'jQuery'];

    function expandableDivContent($timeout, $) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngFormCtrl) {

                scope.expandContent = function () {
                    var $box = $(element).find('.expandablecontent');
                    var $header = $(element).find('.expand');

                    var minimumHeight = 50;
                    // get current height
                    var currentHeight = $box.innerHeight();

                    // get height with auto applied
                    var autoHeight = $box.css('height', 'auto').innerHeight();

                    // reset height and revert to original if current and auto are equal
                    $box.css('height', currentHeight)
                        .animate({
                            height: (currentHeight === autoHeight ? minimumHeight : autoHeight)
                        });

                    var text = currentHeight === autoHeight ? '+ MORE' : '- LESS';
                    $header.text(text);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My css for this

```
.expandablecontent {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 25px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

As I have line-height=25px and max height as 50px it shows 2 lines initially without ellipsis "...."

This is my html

```
<div expandable-div-content ng-if="step.comments">
                    <p class="expandablecontent">
                        <small>"{{step.comments}}"</small>
                    </p>
                    <div class="expand" ng-click="expandContent()" ng-if="step.comments.length > 50">
                         + More
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This works perfectly but I need to display more link only if text exceeds more than 2 lines and the container is responsive my current condition to display link if text is more than 50 characters fails as when the container is resized more than 50 characters can fit into two lines.

How could I display more link conditionally by using a scope variable in directive which helps me determine that text is more than x number of lines which works in all modern browsers.

Comment: maybe this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53753528/5155810

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like, if you know your line height to be say 18px/em what ever, set the height of the container div (of text to be displayed, if you need to create one) to be (n * x)px/em and then add overflow-hidden, with text-overflow: ellipsis.