# How to ensure that a line of text of a certain width never wraps?

Tags: jquery, css

I have some divs with `ul > li` lists in them. Each item should be one line tall and should not wrap. Ideally, ellipses `...` should be inserted for lines that would otherwise wrap: these `li` items should be prevented from wrapping.

Is it possible to accomplish this with through a combination of css and jQuery?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/javascript-insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this solution using jQuery to decrement the length of the string until it fits inside the desired dimension. http://jsfiddle.net/3jwLU/

Answer (score 2):

Add `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

Unfortunately, it's not supported by Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 `text-overflow` property.

If that's not an option you have a lot of jQuery plugins that do what you want. Just search for ellipses in jQuery plugins page...