# how to break the long word in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating list dynamically in javascript. I want to break the long word in as dot dot dot(.....). For example, if the word is "Software life cycle development" I want to change it as "Software life cycl....".

And I used "WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;white-space:normal;"
My current output is:

Software life cycle
 development.

Can anyone tell, how to fix this? thanks in advance.

```
  var parent = document.getElementById('searchlistview');
var listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.setAttribute('id', 'listitem_' + listId);
listItem.setAttribute('data-icon', 'false');
listItem.innerHTML = "<img src=" + imagesrc + " class='ui-li-icon ui-li-has-icon'></img>
<a target='_black' data-role='button' href='#' id=" + listId + " name= " + url + " data-theme ='c' rel='external' 
data-inline='true' style='margin-left:0em; WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;white-space:normal; ' >" + searchName + "<p style='margin-top:1px;margin-left:1px;'>
File size: " + fileSize + "</p></a>";
parent.appendChild(listItem);
```

Comment: Have you tried the psuedo-algorithm: if length-of-string>n string<=left(string,n); string<=concatenate(string, "...")? By the way, we use an ellipsis, which is exactly three dots, to indicate an omitted part.

Comment: @Krish: I never heard about psuedo-algorithm. Can you explain little bit more with example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert ellipsis (...) into HTML tag if content too wide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this css

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

It would put `...` when the text overflow. see this [page](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-overflow/) for your reference.

Answer (score 3):

see if css ellipsis can help you. You can find more details at

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

http://mattsnider.com/css/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function wbr(str, num) { 
  return str.replace(RegExp("(\\w{" + num + "})(\\w)", "g"), function(all,text,char){
    return text + "<wbr>" + char;
  });
}
```

Source: http://ejohn.org/blog/injecting-word-breaks-with-javascript/

Comment: Please acknowledge your source

Answer (score 1):

```
style="text-overflow: ellipsis;"
```

will solve the problem.