# I want to truncate a text or line with DOTS using JavaScript but that start and end of string is visible (like dropbox.com does)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to truncate a text or line with DOTS using JavaScript **but** I need to display the end (filename after slash) and start. Something like dropbox.com does on their website.

I'm looking for jQuery extension or something similar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/536814/402706

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work. You should be able to wrap some of this in a jQuery function or just use the styling directly as part of your markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/4Lruv/ - tested Chrome only