# css how to implement multi-line text field using div with ellipsis

Tags: css, html, text, ellipsis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert ellipsis (…) into HTML tag if content too wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide)
>   [With CSS, use “…” for overflowed block of multi-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines)

Hi I am trying to have a div tag to display a question
this div box is constrained by size, because of the lay out specification
this div tag should show as much text as it can, if it can't show all, it should have ellipsis (i.e. .....) at the end

currently i want it to display maximum 3 lines in that div

if it is more than 3 lines, than it will show ellipsis

example:

This is a question,
from follow student
who attended...

my current style for that div tag is the following:

```
 .question {
    max-height: 40px;
    max-width:200px
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: auto;
 }
```

this doesn't do the trick...
please help

Comment: Multiline isn't supported. You will need javascript to support this. See these two SO questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide

Comment: Put a jsfiddle or any working example, this will be easy to encounter real problem

Comment: added example plesae help http://jsfiddle.net/prWkN/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add "overflow: hidden" to the above

Comment: that didn't fix it sir. it only shows the letters that can fit in the box, rest are 'hidden', no ellipis shown

Comment: This cannot be done with pure CSS.  You'll need JavaScript to do multi-line ellipsis on the client side.  There's lots of jQuery plugins available that do this today.