# CSS Text-overflow Ellipsis Not Displaying

Tags: ellipsis, css

I have a div with some inner content that I need to have an ellipsis when it overflows.  I've done this many times on other elements but for some reason this is not behaving as expected.

Also, I left `white-space:nowrap;` out on purpose because the content then does not break to the next line within the span, as a result I only see 2-3 words before the ellipsis starts.  I would like the text to span the entire height of the parent container then have the ellipsis start for content that exists beyond those bounds.

Here is a working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sadmicrowave/DhkSA/

CSS:

```
.flow-element{
     position:absolute;
     font-size:12px;
     text-align:center;
     width:75px;
     height:75px;
     line-height:70px;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.flow-element .inner{
     position:absolute;
     width:80%;
     height:80%;
     border:1px solid blue;
     top:0px;
     bottom:0px;
     left:0px;
     right:0px;
     margin:auto;
     text-align:center;
}

.flow-element .long{
     float:left;
     height:50px;
     width:100%;
     line-height:12px;
     border:1px solid red;  
     text-overflow:ellipsis;
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class='flow-element' style='top:100px; left:50px;'>
  <div class='inner'>
     <span class='long'>Box 1 and some other content that should wrap and do some other stuff</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Can someone please help.  I need to display as much text as possible within the red outlined span while having an ellipsis when text content overflows the container...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 43, accepted):

you can't apply `text-overflow: ellipsis` to inline elements (span), it can be used with block elements only (div)

and also use `white-space:nowrap;` when using `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

check this, i have converted your inner span to div, just for proof of concept

http://jsfiddle.net/3CgcH/5/

i don't know why you have used span, but as per your logic you can make changes as i suggested

**Update:**

someone will think that in the question if i put `white-space: nowrap;` to span element then the `text-overflow: ellipsis:` is working so may be i am wrong, but it is not the case because questioner has used `float: left` in the span tag that means the span tag will be converted to a box block and work like a normal block level element, which is also wrong thing to do because if you need the block element behavior then use a block level element

**Reference:**

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-float

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#text-overflow

Comment: that is absolutely wrong. works very nice with inline elements.

Comment: then why this w3c draft says that it applies to block contains only ? http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#text-overflow

Comment: `white-space:nowrap;` is what I was missing

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party but `overflow:hidden` also made it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it helped to set display: block;

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

to .flow-element .long

then the overflow-ellispsis works.

Comment: please see my comment to Heather Walters' post of the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find the problem is caused by having text-align: center;

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` to your .inner div.

Comment: adding your suggestion does indeed add the ellipsis to the text however the text does not wrap to the width of the inner element.  I need to show as much of the text as I can, not just 2-3 words of it...

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and was working on a solution that would wrap further than one line....

Comment: @sadmicrowave: You don't understand how text-overflow works. You want to see more? Then you must enlarge the width.

Comment: @Sven, would I not be able to increase the height and also see more?

Comment: no, the problm is, that text-overflow don't really works without white-space:nowrap. And that means you have only one line of text.

Comment: disappointing. can you think of any other way to achieve my intended results?

Comment: A quick search brought this SO jquery solution for both single and multiline ellipses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide

Comment: Did you ever get this working correctly?  I'd love to know how you achieved it if you did!