# text-overflow and multiple line div?

Tags: html, css

I want to create multiline div with text-overflow: ellipsis but the div has only one line.

see example:
http://cssdesk.com/CDS4V

thanks

Comment: As there is already a sufficient workaround as an answer, this is a comment.  This, unfortunately, is not possible with css alone, as `text-overflow:ellipsis` requires `whitespace:no-wrap`, which forces only one line.  For multiple lines, you'll have to use a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wanting a similar effect, and I ended up using the [jquery dotdotdot plugin](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).  I found it pretty easy to use and it worked like magic :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you needed different solutions, here is another person who asked a similar question:

[Insert ellipsis (...) into HTML tag if content too wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide)