# jquery or javascript: Truncate text in table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to truncate the text in the first column of a table using javascript or jQuery. Here's where I'm at:

The table:

```
<table id="bigTable">
    <tr><td>Text is tooooo looong</td><td>Just Right</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text is tooooo looong</td><td>Just Right</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text is tooooo looong</td><td>Just Right</td></tr>
</table>
```

Trying stuff like the following without success ( compiled from other similar posts ):

```
var lbl = $("#bigTable tbody");
var newLbl = $(lbl[0].outerHTML);
$('td:eq(0)', newLbl).slice(5);
```

It does not seem to be getting the contents, or text from the cells. Has no effect whatsoever. Tried also -

```
$('td:eq(0)', newLbl)contents().slice(5);


$('td:eq(0)', newLbl).text().slice(5);
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Before more down-voting and general grumpy-ness occurs ...
I have to have the text from a div copied to a variable for manipulation and later display in a different window/div.
This happens in response to a button click.

...but applying the css rules sounds promising. Will try that instead.

Please see this fiddle to understand what I need to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vsse3/2/

I have to be able to wrap column cells with a div before using the css idea.

Comment: You could do this with just css `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis`. Try it out see if it works...

Comment: This code is awful.  Also, it's already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide

Comment: It might help if you made a jsfiddle

Comment: It has to truncate the text after a button is clicked. But maybe I could apply the css styles via jQuery after that. Yes, the code is awful ...you know, uh ...advice is usually welcome. I suck at javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need js, using CSS:

**demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/vTDAQ/3/

*@elckarns* comment is correct but you also need to wrap the cell content in a `div` to use `text-overflow`.

Also note that your table is not well formed.

**demo updated as requested:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Vsse3/6/

Comment: I've tried this and my width specification is not being obeyed.

Comment: then you are implementing this wrong. Post a jsfiddle with your problem.

Comment: not well-formed indeed.  `<td></td><th></th>` instead of `<td></th><th></td>` might help

Comment: Please see this fiddle for what I need to do to implement what you suggest. And thank you very much for your patience!!! http://jsfiddle.net/Vsse3/2/

Comment: @Peter ~ Thanks! That's perfect!