# jQuery ellipsis plugin won't work with "max-height"

Tags: jquery, plugins, ellipsis, css

I need to be able to use this plugin with the "max-height" css, right now it only works if I define a definite height, but not if it has max-height instead. would there be a way to make that work too?

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.ellipsis = function()
        {
                return this.each(function()
                {
                        var el = $(this);

                        if(el.css("overflow") == "hidden")
                        {
                                var text = el.html();
                                var multiline = el.hasClass('multiline');
                                var t = $(this.cloneNode(true))
                                        .hide()
                                        .css('position', 'absolute')
                                        .css('overflow', 'visible')
                                        .width(multiline ? el.width() : 'auto')
                                        .height(multiline ? 'auto' : el.height())
                                        ;

                                el.after(t);

                                function height() { return t.height() > el.height(); };
                                function width() { return t.width() > el.width(); };

                                var func = multiline ? height : width;

                                while (text.length > 0 && func())
                                {
                                        text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
                                        t.html(text + "...");
                                }

                                el.html(t.html());
                                t.remove();
                        }
                });
        };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we can make a new variable to check for the existence of the maxHeight property, we'll need to clean it up though.

```
var myHeight = (el.css('maxHeight')) ? el.css('maxHeight').split('px')[0] : el.height();
```

If there is a maxHeight, we'll get a value like `500px`, we don't want the `px`, so we've split the string and taken the first piece of the array, which is the raw integer.

Now we can just replace `el.height()` with `myHeight` and you'll get the maxHeight if available, otherwise you'll get the height property.

Comment: Ok great thanks, but where am I suppose to put it in this plugin and such?

Comment: You mean where does the code I provided go, or where does the entire plugin go?

Comment: The code I provided will go after `var el = $(this);`. The only other thing you have to do is find any instance of `el.height()` and change it to `myHeight` -- with the exception of the `el.height()` i provided in my code.

Comment: Okay, well I have changed it all, the problem is that the dots aren't showing (only when using "max-height", they show fine with "height"), so i'm not sure why the 3 dots aren't being placed there as they should.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the max-height is not taken into consideration in jQuery's height().  I made it work by changing the plugin to accept a max_height argument rather than doing the max-height in css:

```
$.fn.ellipsis = function(max_height)
```

Then change the height function:

```
function height() { return t.height() > max_height; };
```

Not super elegant but it illustrates the problem.

By the way, the original code from above comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022672/986840