# How to show ellipsis on a readonly input field in Android stock browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you set an input field to show ellipsis if the text is too long? The input field is read only and its width is set to 100%.

Is this possible? If not, how do you do it in JavaScript?

Note: While this seems to work on Chrome, it does not work on the Android stock browser.

My current css for the input field:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert ellipsis (...) into HTML tag if content too wide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: The above link is regarding a generic html tag. My question is specific to the input field. I was able to display ellipsis on the html tags but not on an input field. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a specific question about a special case, it should be presented that way (preferably with a reference to the general case). From the comments, it seems that you are having problems with a particular browser. Due clarifications should be made into the text and possibly title of the *question*, not just in comments.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Thanks for the advice! I already updated my title.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your requirements, you can use CSS's [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#Opera_notes) to achieve this:

HTML:

```
<input disabled="disabled" value="really really long text that will be trunked" />
```

CSS

```
input{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yrPc8/

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment! I also text-overflow with width but it still does not show the ellipsis on the Android stock browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101678/829533) will help you

You can create a class and apply it on your `textbox` 
**HTML**

```
<input type="text" readonly value="Lorem ispum dolor sit amit Lorem ispum dolor sit amit Lorem ispum dolor sit amit Lorem ispum dolor sit amit " class="ellipsis">
```

**CSS**

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**To Fix the Android CSS text-overflow issues according to [Ben](http://www.chilisapps.com/blog/2013/04/18/css-text-overflow-issues-on-android/)**

```
*{
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Check it live here http://jsfiddle.net/b4YjX/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this does not work on the Android browser. My current code is the same with yours minus the `-o-text-overflow`. While it works on Chrome, it does not work on the Android stock browser.

Comment: @Arci: can you have a look at this? http://www.chilisapps.com/blog/2013/04/18/css-text-overflow-issues-on-android/

Comment: Thanks for the link! However, it does not solve my problem. I also tried the `optimizeLegibility` property but the input field still does not show ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

The following code has been tested and it works,I hope that will help !

```
.input{
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! But your answer is the same as the other commenters. However, this does not work on Android stock browser.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a limitation/bug in the Android browser: it seems to fail to implement `text-overflow: ellipsis` on any `input` element.

For example, instead of `<input name=foo value="some long string here" width=100%>`, you could use

```
<style>
.hidden { 
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%; 
}
</style>
<div class=hidden>some long string here</div>
<input type=hidden name=foo value="some long string here">
```

For a readonly field, there is a simple workaround: duplicate the data, first in (say) `div` element, on which you set `text-overflow: ellipsis`, and then in a hidden field. You may wish to style the first element to look like a readonly field, but keeping it as normal text would make it even clearer to the user that this data cannot be edited using normal means.

As usual with small devices, you normally need something like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` to make `100%` correspond to actual device width.