# CSS issue with nesting white-space: normal; inside parent of white-space: nowrap; - Parent no longer has correct width

Tags: html, css, whitespace, nowrap

I'm trying to figure out why my parent element loses it's width when I do this? Please see my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ks3Qu/

**HTML**

```
        <h1>white-space: normal; on < a > tag breaks the ul's width but gives desired text effect.</h1>

        <div class="clear">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="no" href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="no"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="no"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="no"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="no"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="no"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="no"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="no"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="no"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="no"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="no"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="no"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="no"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>




        <h1>white-space: nowrap; is inherited from  < ul > tag to < a > tag now has full width of background (almost?) but loses desired text effect</h1>
        <div class="clear">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="yes" href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="yes"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="yes"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="yes"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="yes"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="yes"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="yes"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="yes"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="yes"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="yes"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="yes"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="yes"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
                <li><a class="yes"  href="">This This This This This This This This This</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    /* Universal */
    *, *:after, *:before { margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; list-style: none;  }
    * :focus { outline: 0; }

    /* Clear Fix*/
    .clear:before, .clear:after { content: " " !important; display: table !important; }
    .clear:after { clear: both !important; }
    .clear { *zoom: 1 !important; clear: both !important; }

    /* Normal Elements */
    h1 { margin: 2em 0 0; }
    div { width: auto; margin: 0 auto; }
    ul { float: left; white-space: nowrap; background: lime; } /* LIME background shows ul's width */
    li { display: inline-block; max-width: 10em; }

    /* Problem Elements */
    a.no { white-space: normal; } /* Normal breaks width */
    a.yes {  } /* Nowrap fixes ul width (almost?) */
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `word-wrap: break-word;` helps you you have very long code but its clear i understand your need this will help you. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VivekNadar/PhqnM/2/) and refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329754/ellipsis-at-end-in-multiline-statement/18329949#18329949) moreover which is not a parent problem `padding` left right also clear it.

```
ul.lisits{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul.lisits > li{
    display:inline-block;
}
ul.lisits > li > a{
     word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

other thing is in case of fixed div or ul `text-overflow:ellipsis` and `white-space:nowrap` will help :)