# how to keep the words always remain at its position on its current line in different browsers, and when zooming?

Tags: javascript, css, html, words

I made a simple DIV with justified text like this

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz2BE)

I want to keep content inside the `DIV` unchanged when I open it in different browsers, the number of characters in any line must be the same in different browsers, and when i zoom it in/out.

but the problem is the text in `DIV` is always rearranged (few characters are felt down to the next line) when I view it in different browsers like Chrome, IE, Firefox.. especially when i zoom it in or out.

for example, i have a DIV in chrome like that

```
AAA BBBB CCC DDDDD

EEEEE FF GGGGG HHH
```

but in FireFox or when i zoom, it turns to

```
AAA BBBB CCC DDDD

DEEEEE FF GGGGG H

HH
```

how to keep this identical in all browsers? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: sorry, i just added it back

Comment: please try this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: i just checked your solution on chrome, IE, FF, opera and safari, the contents is not identical..

Comment: I think you are asking like this [question related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329754/ellipsis-at-end-in-multiline-statement/18329949#18329949) check this..because am not clear with ur question

Comment: sorry for my bad english, i update the question again. please check it out

Answer (score 1):

If you set the width of the div in `em`s then the width will be relative to the font-size. That should allow the div to stay relatively the same size when you zoom across browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/hz2BE/6/

#### CSS

```
#text1{
    text-align:justify;
    text-justify:inter-word;
    width: 20em;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i checked it on my macbook, the paragraph looks identical on chrome & safari. however it's not the same when i open the link on nexus7 and ipad mini. also it looks different on windows, between the browsers