# Slice text within width of p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `p tag with fix width`. If a long sentence came then that sentence should be sliced automatically like in the figures below.

[image]

So this sentence should show like this.

[image]

I tried many Css options like `word-wrap and text-overflow` but nothing work. Some makes width increase and some make other issues. I also tried `overflow:hidden`, this hides second line but did not add `...` at the end of first line.

Comment: Have you looked in to truncation plugins such as http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/ ?

Comment: you must use ellipsis in text-overflow style with overflow hidden.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use :

```
p {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display block;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;     
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ezywm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Check this previous stackoverflow question for this answer
[Insert ellipsis (...) into HTML tag if content too wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide)

We can make this effect with the help of jQuery also.

check out the [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) jQuery plugin.

**CSS3:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ellipsis</title>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
   p {
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 2px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 250px;
       } 
    </style>
    <body>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```