# Adding ellipsis using jquery if cell text exceeds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span tag in a table header below which is a multiline text and I want to add an ellipsis (...) 
If the line exceeds more than with in the cell with jQuery or JavaScript. I cannot use any CSS or jQuery plugins.

```
<span class=​"co_dcrTable_Header" style=​"width:​ auto;​">​Market capitalization at filing​</span>​
```

Comment: How can't you use CSS?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan lol javascript does not equal jquery

Comment: i can use jquery but not any plugins in jqyery. Trying to avoid css. I think using javscript/jquery there should be a way ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex very good point ;) missed the JS tag

Comment: yeah i looked at it . Below is the modified code i have written.

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex  can u look at the prob in answer and let me know the issue please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
            if(el.css("overflow") == "hidden")
            {
                var text = el.html();
                var t = $(this.cloneNode(true))
                .hide()
                .css('position', 'absolute')
                .css('overflow', 'visible')
                .width(el.width())
                .height('auto');

                el.after(t);

                while (text.length > 0 && (t.height() > el.height()))
                {
                    text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
                    t.html(text + "...");
                }

                el.html(t.html());
                t.remove();
            }
```

I have the above code it is not going into the while block since the condition t.height() > el.height() is failing as both heights are showing equal values . I have the span tag with the text