# text-overflow ellipsis in fluid width table cells

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a fluid width table where text in the cells isn't allowed to flow onto another line and will use `text-overflow:ellipsis` when it is too long to fit.

I tried the following test:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec feugiat placerat risus. Maecenas lectus orci, commodo id varius ac, vulputate eget elit. Nunc laoreet feugiat aliquet.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table { width: 100%; }

td { 
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```

But as you can see in the fiddle below, the ellipsis doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/p3pXc/

Is there a solution?

Comment: Actually all text is in the same row for me.

Comment: @user3501411 yes but does the text start using text-overflow:ellipsis for you?

Comment: Ah sorry didn't understand the question...
If you wish to have three dotts in the end just add max-width.

Comment: he specifically asked for  fluid width...

Comment: @user3501411 yes I need fluid width, so can't use specific widths or max-widths

Comment: So what _should_ your “fluid width” depend on then …? If you don’t apply _any_ restrictions, then the width of the cell is determined by the length of the text – and then _of course_ it is not cut off with an ellipsis at the end. You need to be more specific as to what you _actually_ want here, before that this question makes little sense.

Comment: @CBroe I explained clearly and if you read the code I posted you should also understand. The table is set to 100% width. In the fiddle you'll see that is also 100% width of the body and html. In live production that would be the width of the device. At the moment the text in the cell pushes the boundary of the cell past 100% width.

Comment: Well then simply adding `table { table-layout:fixed; }` should solve your problem …

Comment: Ah yes it does! That seems like the kind of answer I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is now way to have the CSS ellipsis on a dynamic width element.

Adding

```
display: block;
width: 300px;
```

for example, will create your ellipsis. But this will not do, in your case.

You will have to fallback on a JavaScript solution, like `jquery.ellipsis` plugin.
See this question for more information: [Insert ellipsis (...) into HTML tag if content too wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide)

---

**Edit:**

Actually, if you just want the column to extend to all the width of the table, without crossing out of the screen (and keeping it only on one line), you should add

```
table { 
    width: 100%; 
    table-layout: fixed; 
}
```

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7v72L/

(thanks to @CBroe for the suggestion)

Comment: Oh that is disappointing if that's true. Shame it doesn't suck so much and just do what you want it to do!

Comment: I'll have to give you the points seeing as @CBroe didn't answer properly, but credit goes to him for that one.

Comment: I credited him, but if he puts up an answer, feel free to pull of the selection from my answer and give it to him. In the end, what matters is that the answer is there for the community

Comment: Awesome ! I made the modifications to my css snippet and it works pretty good ! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWPpKd

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, this problem is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492253/fluid-table-truncate-cell-contents-when-needed-otherwise-keep-the-table-as-nar), achieving the effect illustrated below:

[image: Fluid table illustration]