# Convert type string to type Text on Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, text, types

I want to create a searcher on my website, the problem is that when I show the results of my database, some have a very large description and I'm trying to trunc the description in order to make it more visual.

What I want to do is to show a description that should be like this:

> blablabla description bla bla bla more description

into this:

> blablabla description bla bla bla mo...

The maximum length that I want to show is 340 characters and the code that I was thinking of is this one

```
...
    var newText = document.createElement("p"); //i create a new element of text
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(projects.description); //i set the text to
        //be the description from the database [the type of this var is Text]
    if(newContent.length > 340) {  //if the description is bigger than 340
         var result=newContent + "";  //i convert the newContent type to string since 
              //substring only works with strings and not Text
         result=result.substring(0, 337)+"...";  //i trunc the description
         newContent=result;  // <-- here i need to assign the result[string] to newContent[Text]
    }
    newText.appendChild(newContent);
...
```

Hope you can tell me how to convert the string to Text again or another way to trunc the description.

Thanks, Bertran

Comment: Looks like you already got a string value in `projects.description` – so modify that to your needs, and create a text node from it _afterwards_.

Comment: Or use what CSS has to offer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: why dont try `if (projects.description.length > 340)` ....? then do whatever you want with the text and finally put it into p element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are passing a reference to a string, rather than a reference to a text node, to the `appendChild` method of the paragraph element you've created.

```
var newContent = document.createTextNode(projects.description);
```

On this line, you create a text node, and place a reference to this text node into the variable `newContent`.

```
newContent = result;
```

On this line, you replace the value of the variable `newContent` with a reference to a string you've created.

### Solutions

You have many options for solutions, but here are two obvious ones.

One solution would be to access the `nodeValue` property of your text node in order to set its contents:

```
var newContent = document.createTextNode(projects.description);

if (newContent.nodeValue.length > 340)
    newContent.nodeValue = newContent.nodeValue.substring(0, 337) + '...';
```

Another option would be to pass the `createTextNode` parameter the right string the first time. A ternary operator could work well here:

```
var newContent = document.createTextNode(
        projects.description.length > 340
        ? projects.description.substring(0, 337) + '...'
        : projects.description);
```

Now, when you append `newContent` to your paragraph element `newText`, it will be passing a reference to a text node, and not a string.

```
newText.appendChild(newContent);
```

Here is a [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/RLf46/).

---

Note, user @epascarello commented that a CSS rule exists to automatically add ellipses to text without the need for JavaScript. Here is a [link to an explanation of the rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow). Note that this is a CSS3 rule.

---

Here is another StackOverflow Q&A that deals with the premise of this question.

- [Insert ellipsis (…) into HTML tag if content too wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide)