# Grid view overflows outside its defined width

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

I have a div with 2 grid views each occupying 50% of the div width.

The last column of the first grid view contains names which are about 200 characters long.

As a result of this it continues to the second grid view.

I don't want to use scrollbars.

Is there any way I can limit the first grid view to 50% and **display dots(...) in the column** after its width is over ?

**Code for the first grid view :**

```
<div style="width:50%;height:300px;float:left;" align="left">
      <asp:GridView ID = "UnanalysedGV" runat ="server" DataSourceID = "sourceProducts" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" CssClass="mGrid headerclass" AllowSorting="True" Width="100%" AllowPaging="true" >     
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <Columns>              
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "Id" HeaderText = " Id" /> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "Owner" HeaderText = "Owner"  />

                             <asp:BoundField DataField="eName" HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />


                      </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>

            </div>
```

Similarly,for the second grid view.

Comment: can u show us ur html and css?

Comment: Sure.Give me a minute!

Comment: Any information on how to go about it would also be very very helpful :)

Comment: Have no idea , sorry

Comment: Okay.Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: Hi,  I have looked into this for my own page, but have not found anything that works good :/

Comment: Take a look at this question with answers... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide

Comment: Okay..Thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this :

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left"> 
                                <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="width: 150px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                                    <%# Eval("Name") %>
                           </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```