# how to generate "..." after certain words in a paragraph. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a long paragraph but i only want to show some portion of it.
Is it possible to generate "..." after some words.

for example, this is my paragraph.

```
 <div class="paragraph">
 <p>Lore gypsum dolor sit met, con sec tetuer dip icings lite. Aeneid commodore ligula beget dolor. Aeneid mas- s. Cum socialist toque Pentiums lit something something</p>
 </div>
```

and i want to show in the page like "Lore gypsum dolor sit me ...."

Comment: You can use CSS's `text-overflow` property.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1022672/5305938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

```
.paragraph{
 white-space: nowrap; 
width: 120px; 
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

for more details http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Comment: This won't work when you want to specify a certain amount of words..

Comment: You can apply width to your class that will solve your issues

Comment: To address the comment, this will _not_ work when you want to specify a number of _words_. It will if you specify a _width_, but if there is a hard requirement (however how foolish) for words, you're out of luck (with CSS). As an honourable mention, for monospaced fonts you can use the [`ch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#ch) unit, which would allow you to insert an ellipsis after a certain amount of _characters_.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
.paragraph {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/jxo6cjap/)